# Azure Dev-ops security

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I'm trying to configure my Azure Dev-ops setup so I can expose just a repo to a client, rather than boards / wiki and all the other options.

How do I configure a group or team in dev-ops so that members of that group or team are NOT able to see anything other than a specific repo from my organization (ie they're able to pull from the repo but not even see boards,tasks,wiki etc from the same project)

I've tried doing a number of processes by following the guides and documentation which hasn't yielded a 'cut-down' view of the dev-ops project to my test email.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this via the Project Settings page.

Create a new security group
[image]

Then set the permissions.  I applied the "deny" permission to every single item except "View project-level information."

[image]

Then in the Project Settings go down to Repos and click Repositories.  Add your new security group to the repositories and set the permissions you want the group to have.

[image]

Remember that when you add users to the new group to make sure they are removed from other groups to limit their access.  The menu items for boards, pipelines, etc will still show on the menu but when a user goes into them they can't see or create anything.

Comment: This didn't work for me followed it by the letter and my test user was still able to create tasks etc.

Comment: Did you remove them from any other groups?

Comment: Yep I did. It's a little frustrating as imo if it were possible it should hide the menu items as well. Devops does so much of what we need it just falls short by this 10%

Comment: Is this really a deal breaker?  I mean it covers 90% of what you need it to do and it really isn't a functional issue at this point

Comment: when working for clients it's sometimes important to silo out access to the repo away from tasks & the rest that dev-ops offers so clients can see and access the work being done and possibly contribute. without needing to be concerned with the rest of dev-ops.  Being able to switch access on / off seems like a pretty straight forward ask tbh.  I'm reluctant to look at Jira & its source control integration and see if that can offer the kind of access control I'm looking  for, but it's looking more and more likely that may be the way forward.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I configure a group or team in dev-ops so that members of that
>   group or team are NOT able to see anything other than a specific repo
>   from my organization

For this demand, I am afraid it is not feasible in azure devops.
Regardless of how permissions are set, both the Overview and Boards are visible.

The only way I know of setting Overview and boards to invisible is to turn off the service in the project settings Overview, but this will make the service invisible to all members of the project.

[image]

I met some users have the same needs as you, you could raise your feature demand [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21) to promote development of richer features or vote for the same Uservoice to increase priority.